# How to create url for each file entry in database (liferay) and download it

Tags: file, liferay

I have a table that contains a file **id** and a file content saved as **clob** type.
Now I want to create a link programmatically for each file and download via it.

How this is possible?

I have created my link but I have no idea how to get file from that link.

```
String fileUrl = themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathContext() + "/files/"
            + themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() + "/Folder/" + HttpUtil.encodeURL(HtmlUtil.unescape(String.valueOf(fileId)));
```

Comment: Give this fileurl to href attribute of anchor tag. Clicking on link will download that file.

Comment: There is no file there. First I have to get file from database and put it on that location.

Comment: I see you are saving file in db.

Comment: Yes I am saving it to db.
But I have a problem.
How can I get realpath using getPortletContext().getRealPath("/")  in my jsp file?

Comment: You can utilize DLContentLocalServiceUtil when you are saving files to db

Comment: You can write serveResource method which would contain logic for getting file from database by DLContentLocalServiceUtil utility methods and set those file[bytes] in response with appropriate content type set. And anchor links will have resourceUrl which will call serveResource

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your own service for you custom table (Service created by `Liferay Service Builder`).

What you can do is that at the page load, you can create the `<portlet:resourceURL>` links with id as a parameter.

When user clicks this, the `serveResource()` method will be called. Here, just call your service and get the data by passing id. Take that data and write the data into `OutputStream` and provide the valid `Content-Type`.

This should work, as the main purpose of `serveResource()` is to serve resource! :)